# GoogleAppsScript for Calendar vs Google CalendarAPI

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

What are the general usecases and considerations to go for [Google Apps Script for Calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_calendar) vs [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple the Google Apps Script use cases are:

- a site, built using the [Google Apps Sites](http://www.google.com/sites/overview.html), which handles the Calendar;
- an add-on to the Google Spreadsheets which handles the Calendar.

Simple the Google Calendar API use cases are:

- a stand-alone site, written using, for instance, Java or ASP.NET, which manipulates the Calendar.
- an utility program, written using similar languages and libraries as in the topic above, for instance Java or C#, which synchronizes an internal company calendar system database with the Calendar.